# What do "Templar" and "Soldiers of Christ" mean?

Tags: church-history, terminology

I have been hearing a lot about Templars in movies such as *Ironclad* and games like *Assassin's Creed*. I did a quick look up on Google about "Templars" and still haven't got any clue on what is it about.

Who are the Templars? What does Soldier of Christ mean? How are the Templars linked to Soldiers of Christ? And are all Christians soldiers of Christ?

Comment: I like this question... I almost asked it myself the other day.  But I think maybe the last sentence doesn't belong... In a sense, yes, all Christians are "soldiers of Christ" (with a small 's'), but by no means are the all "Soldiers of Christ" (with big 'S').  IOW, they obviously aren't members of an organization with that name...

Comment: @Flimzy imagine if there was...

Comment: keep in mind, it's very likely movies and video games have made them something else than their true identity, cause, etc...kind of like Jesus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official name of the Knights Templar is "Poor Fellow-Soldiers of Christ and of the Temple of Solomon".  So the "Soldiers of Christ" you mention is probably just another name for the same group.

Wikipedia has an excellent article on the Knights Templar.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_Templar

A biblical reference to us being soldiers of Christ is in 2 Timothy 2.  I believe here we are being told to try to please Christ rather than others.

> **[2 Timothy 2:3-4 NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%202:3-4&version=NIV)** (emphasis mine)
>   3 Join with me in suffering, like a good **soldier of Christ Jesus**. 4 No
>   one serving as a soldier gets entangled in civilian affairs, but
>   rather tries to please his commanding officer.